To stop updating TODAY() - excel
I added a formula that excel to add todays date in one column (C) when I add any text in another column (D). My problem is that I want to stop updating the todays date (in column C), after I added any comment in column D. I tried all formulas and VBAs that I find in the internet, but when I open the excel the the dates always are updated to the current date.
Can anyone help me? Thank you!

I tried formulas and VBAs recommended by internet, by users.
I hope someone can help with a VBA solution, that stops update just today() formula, but keep updating the other formulas. Ex. when I add text in column D still will add the today date in column C, but after that will not updated.

You will need to use VBA to add the date value in Col C: you can't use a formula for this, since as you've noticed it will always keep updating when the sheet calculates.. Please update your question to add the VBA you tried, and explain exactly what wasn't working when you ran it.

Seems like a lot of hard work just to add todays date when a comment is entered.  MIght be easier to use Ctrl+; to enter todays date in the cell when needed.

Here's a fancier non-VBA solution:
Allow iterative calculations, but you'll never need more than 1 iteration to reach the desired value, so set the Maximum Iterations to 1 to prevent any slow-down in your workbook. (See settings screenshot in my first answer.)
Enter this formula in the first cell and fill down:
=IF(D3="","",IF(C3="",TODAY(),C3))


The date will be blank until a value is entered in D3. When a value is first entered in D3, C3 is blank at that time, so it initially evaluates to Today. After any other change that triggers recalculation, C3 will continue to be equal to its current value, so it won't change.
Clearing D3 will cause C3 to go blank again.
The only issue is if you enter the formula in C3 when D3 already has a value, C3 will go straight to 0/01/1900, because its current value is 0 on first calculation. To fix this, clear the value in D3 and then reenter the value in D3.

You'll need to create an Excel macro, which responds on the fact that you modify a cell in your Excel sheet, something like:
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
  If Target.Column = 4 Then
    Target.Offset(0, -1).Value = Target.Offset(0, -1).Value
  End If
End Sub


The Target is the cell which is being altered (in other means, you put a comment in that cell).
If Target.Column = 4: you only want something to happen when you modify something in the fourth column (column "D").
Target.Offset(0, -1): what you want to change, is the cell at the left side of the cell you're changing.
Something.Value = Something.Value: that's a weird one: you take the value, currently present in that cell, and you tell Excel that this should be the "value" of that cell (replacing the formula by its value).


A Worksheet Change: Add Date Stamp
Sheet Module, e.g. Sheet1

Right-click the sheet and select View Code. Copy the following code into the window that opened.
After you add a value in column D it adds a date stamp in column C if not already present.

Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    
    Const TOP_TARGET_CELL_ADDRESS As String = "D3"
    Const DATE_COLUMN As String = "C"
    
    Dim trg As Range, tcell As Range
    
    With Me.Range(TOP_TARGET_CELL_ADDRESS)
        Set trg = Intersect(.Resize(Me.Rows.Count - .Row + 1), Target)
    End With
    
    If trg Is Nothing Then Exit Sub
    
    Dim Today As Date: Today = Date
    
    Application.EnableEvents = False
    
    For Each tcell In trg.Cells
        With tcell.EntireRow.Columns(DATE_COLUMN) ' reference date cell
            If Len(CStr(tcell.Value)) > 0 Then ' target cell is not blank
                If Len(CStr(.Value)) = 0 Then ' date cell is blank
                    .Value = Today
                'Else ' date cell is not blank (already populated); do nothing
                End If
            'Else ' target cell is blank; do nothing?
            '    .Value = Empty ' or clear date cell?
            End If
        End With
    Next tcell
            
    Application.EnableEvents = True

End Sub


Here's a novel non-VBA solution:
Allow iterative calculations, but you'll never need more than 1 iteration to reach the desired value, so set the Maximum Iterations to 1 to prevent any slow-down in your workbook:

Enter this formula in the first cell and fill down:
=IF(D3="",TODAY(),C3)


With every update to the worksheet, the formula in all cells will update to today's date while the adjacent cell is blank (i.e. while the condition is TRUE). After a value has been entered in the adjacent cell, the formula will keep it's current value instead (since the condition is now FALSE).
